# R knitr to HTML Does Not Work I Get an error

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am using the basic skeleton code provided when you open an HTML Rmarkdown knit code and it doesn't work.  I get the same error every time:

output file: practice-run.knit.md

"C:/Users/MAShadden/AppData/Local/Programs/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS practice-run.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output practice-run.html --lua-filter "\pmc-pia-fs01\FS-FS01-C0390-users\MAShadden\MyDocs\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "\pmc-pia-fs01\FS-FS01-C0390-users\MAShadden\MyDocs\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --template "\pmc-pia-fs01\FS-FS01-C0390-users\MAShadden\MyDocs\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\MASHAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0IS3OS\rmarkdown-str34a83cce6cfb.html"
pandoc.exe: \: openBinaryFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted

Knitting to Word and PDF work fine, but HTML never works.

---

### title: "practice markdown"
author: "Me"
date: "3/4/2022"
output: html_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Comment: try upgrading Rstudio as described [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-1/79808).

Comment: I already did. I removed and re-installed both R and RStudio.